# I am Adding and Removing from ObservableCollection but the Grid is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, observablecollection

I am using this code to update my grid. It is not working. Grid is not updating. I cannot find any problem with the code. This is a Help Desk app. I am trying to update a closed ticket on the server with my grid on the client. HELP !

```
public class DAL_LOADTICKETS
{
    private static string URL ="http://helpdesk.hujelabs.com/user.php/"+Login.user_id+"/query/";
    public static void/*ObservableCollection<cTicket>*/ LoadOPENTICKETS()
    {
        // Execute the query using the LINQ to XML

        var tickets = from c in XElement.Load(URL).Elements("query") select c;
        foreach (var ticks in tickets)
        {
            cTicket lTicket = new cTicket
            {
                TicketID = ticks.Element("query_id").Value,
                TicketStatus = ticks.Element("status").Value,
                TicketSubject = ticks.Element("subject").Value,
                TicketDescription = ticks.Element("description").Value,
                TicketTags = ticks.Element("tag").Value,
                TimeStamp = ticks.Element("timestamp").Value,
            };
            if (ticks.Element("status").Value == "open")
            {
                if (!Window1.OpenTicketsList.Contains(lTicket))
                {
                    Window1.OpenTicketsList.Add(lTicket);
                }
            }

            else if (ticks.Element("status").Value == "closed")
            {
                if (Window1.OpenTicketsList.Contains(lTicket))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("VISITED BUT NOT DELETED");

                    Window1.OpenTicketsList.Remove(lTicket);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

```xml
<Grid Width="756" Background="White">
                    <ListView Name="OpenReqList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding TicketCollection}" Width="750" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="OpenReqList_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Ticket ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TicketID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" Header="Ticket Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TicketSubject}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="190" Header="Ticket Send Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TimeStamp}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="190" Header="Ticket Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TicketStatus}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class cTicket
    {
        public string TicketID { get; set; }
        public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
        public string TicketSubject { get; set; }
        public string TicketDescription { get; set; }
        public string TicketTags { get; set; }
        public string TicketDiscussionID { get; set; }
        public string ResponseAdmin { get; set; }
        public string ResponseClient { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also show how you setup the data binding of the Grid to the Window1.OpenTicketsList?

Comment: Can you post your xaml and relevent portions of your ViewModel?

Comment: i have updated the same code block for the xaml

Comment: You seem to be binding to TicketCollection but in the code you manipulate OpenTicketsList. Also can you show the definition of your cTicket, so we can determine how the instance matching is happening.

Comment: i just put in the cTicket class. I cannot seem to find the problem.

Comment: Ticketcollection is a method which returns OpenTicketsList

Comment: @Mohammad Umair Khan, based on everything we see it seems that you Remove will not actually remove the ticket. Please check the collection in the debugger and confirm that the ticket is actually being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is constructing a new Ticket and trying to remove *it* from the ObservableCollection.  Try finding the Ticket that is already in your collection, then removing it.  Alternatively, you may need to override Equals on your Ticket class so ObservableCollection knows that your new Ticket is equal to the old ticket.

Comment: i wrote another method which checks the current collection with the collection on the web. Matches their query_id and checks the status. But on the update it gives this exception:

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: When you use a foreach statement over most collections, the Enumerator will check to make sure the collection has not been modified (added/removed/replaced/cleared).  If the collection has changed since the enumerator was created, the enumerator will throw this exception.  To work around this, `break` out of the loop once you've modified the collection.  Or, you can use one loop to find the objects/indexes that need to be removed, and after the foreach (){}, you can modify the collection.

Comment: I seem to have done it by the method above. Selecting index and removing outside the foreach. Not sure if it is completely BUG free......